# how to send sql files to another computer

Tags: sql-server

I want to send my sql-server files to another computer but I searched and I have to Attach or give backup and Restore files in the Destination computer and I want to know is there another way to send it with out doing anything ?

Comment: Well no... you’d have to do SOMETHING. Research log shipping and database mirroring. These may be what you are looking for. You can also automate your backup and restore job, which is essentially log shipping.

Comment: Check out SSIS packages

Comment: [Try to avoid detach/attach as a backup/restore mechanism](https://blogs.sentryone.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-file-backups/).

Answer (score 0):

you can generate script as the following:
1- right click on the specified db and click 'Generate Scripts' from tasks.
2- click Next to page 'set Scipting Objects' from advanced search about 'types of data to script' choose 'schema and data' and press ok
3- change the place of the saved script and do next for the next steps.
4- now you have the database as script file you can move it anywhere you like.